# Load ModernUI but also preload desktop on background

Tags: windows-8, desktop, modern-ui

1. Login
2. Windows load modern UI
3. **Only when I click on the "Desktop" tile shortcut** that my desktop is really loaded, it take a few seconds to open everything (like rainmeter and other things)

How can I make windows load both modern UI and my desktop on the background? I don't want to skip the modern UI just autoload the desktop.

Similar to add `something.exe` to the startup, but what executable should I use? I've tried `explorer.exe` but didn't work.

Comment: Its not the desktop that is holding things up, it is the applications like rainmeter doing it, not sure there is a solution for this. Is a "few seconds" really a bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 does load the desktop and any applications listed in the Startup group (presumably also the Run registry key) in the background after loading the start screen. This seems to occur a little later then if triggered manually but it is loaded automatically.

There is currently no native way to make it show the desktop automatically.